# Unable to acces element while having a SRE match using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I scrape the page like this:

```
s1 =bs4DerivativePage.find_all('table',class_='not-clickable zebra’)
```

With output:

```
[<table class="not-clickable zebra" data-price-format="{price}" data-quote-detail="0" data-stream-id="723288" data-stream-quote-option="Standard">
 <tbody><tr>
 <td><strong>Stop loss-niveau</strong></td>
 <td>141,80447</td>
 <td class="align-left"><strong>Type</strong></td>
 <td>Turbo's</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><strong>Financieringsniveau</strong></td>
 <td>135,05188</td>
```

I need to retrieve the value from Financieringsniveau.
The following gives a match:

```
finNiveau=re.search('Financieringsniveau’,LineIns1)
```

However I need the numerical value 135,05188. How does one does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.findNext()`

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = """<table class="not-clickable zebra" data-price-format="{price}" data-quote-detail="0" data-stream-id="723288" data-stream-quote-option="Standard">
 <tbody><tr>
 <td><strong>Stop loss-niveau</strong></td>
 <td>141,80447</td>
 <td class="align-left"><strong>Type</strong></td>
 <td>Turbo's</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><strong>Financieringsniveau</strong></td>
 <td>135,05188</td></tr></tbody></table>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
print(soup.find(text="Financieringsniveau").findNext("td").text)  #Search using text and the use findNext
```

**Output:**

```
135,05188
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `data-stream-id` attribute value is unique (in combination with `table` tag) you can use CSS selectors and avoid `re`. This is a fast retrieval method.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<table class="not-clickable zebra" data-price-format="{price}" data-quote-detail="0" data-stream-id="723288" data-stream-quote-option="Standard">
 <tbody><tr>
 <td><strong>Stop loss-niveau</strong></td>
 <td>141,80447</td>
 <td class="align-left"><strong>Type</strong></td>
 <td>Turbo's</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><strong>Financieringsniveau</strong></td>
 <td>135,05188</td>
 '''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('table[data-stream-id="723288"] td:nth-of-type(6)').text)
```